# PHP Trying to bring the name by id

Tags: php, mysqli

Can anyone please check out my code  i don't know what is wrong with him.
    I'm trying to bring the id of city table by the id of the product.
There is something wrong in the while loop $product section that not working well.

```
<?php
    if( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
        while ( $product = $result->fetch_assoc() ) { ?>
            <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
                <a href="#" class="accordion-title">
                    <?php echo $product['product_name']; ?>
                </a>
                <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>price</th>
                                <th>description</th>
                                <th>city</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $product['product_price']; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $product['product_desc']; ?>
                                </td>
                                **/////////this part is not working**
                                <?php   
                                                      while ($city = $cities->fetch_assoc()){
                                                      if($city['id']==$product['city_id']) { ?>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $city['city_name'];} ?>
                                </td>
                                <?php
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php
                }
            } else { 
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                NO CATEGORY FOUND!
            </div>
            <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: what type of data contains by `$cities`??

Comment: id and cityname

Comment: where did you get this? $cities->fetch_assoc() what result you are getting?

Comment: $cities = $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM `cities`" );

Comment: The problem is here: `</td>
                                <?php
                            </tr>`. The purpose of the `<?php` marker here is to contain the `}` that closes the `while` block. It should be: `</td>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </tr>`.

Comment: I didn't get it .can you please change the code?

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in code.You are closing if() before closing  which will result in broken html.Try this code.

```
<?php   
while ($city = $cities->fetch_assoc()){
if($city['id']==$product['city_id']) { 
?> 
<td> <?php echo $city['city_name']; ?> </td>
<?php
}
}
?>
```